# Divide an ordered collection of HTML elements with known heights into pages divs

Tags: jquery, angularjs, html

The mediocre way it is done now:

1. We know the height of each object in advance.
2. We have a collection of such objects that can have a page break between them.
3. We start with a blank and add an opening `<div class="imaPage">`
4. we iterate over items from the collection and render their fragments until we reach an element that would overflow (if we don't do something).
5. When that happens, we add a closing `</div>` and another opening `<div class="ImaPage">` (this is bassically like the page break in Word). -> go back to 4

There has to be a better way to do this? We want to produce a webpage that looks and feels like a report with page breaks in the appropriate places. Please let me know if this makes sense and I will clarify as needed.

Some problems with this method:

- I currently hardcode the height of the elements, not sure how to do that on the fly. What if new elements are added tomorrow or element sizes change?
- I mostly use Angularjs so adding an opening and a closing tag smells bad to me. I don't like to mess with the dom directly if I can avoid it while still keeping it simple.

I really would like it if I could elegantly iterate over all the body's direct children, check the heights (y-position) on the client side and then place the elements into containing divs as needed without getting odd behavior if the page is zoomed into and what not.

It just feels wrong and not very robust, scalable  and maintainable.

Comment: What's wrong with this?  It will do exactly what you say you want.

Comment: It is mostly an implementation issue, I will note the stuff that I feel is wrong and wish to improve. Thanks for pointing out that it's anything but obvious.

Comment: @Archer I edited the question to specify what I wanna change specifically.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use jQuery cause this entirely involves DOM manipulation which I think jQuery is useful for.

The solution I came up with is really simple:

```
function divideToPages(frag, maxHeight, source, destination)
{
  var obj = { 'addToMe' : null,};

  source.children().each(function(index) {
    if (obj.addToMe === null || obj.addToMe.height() + $( this ).height() > maxHeight)
    {
     obj.addToMe = $(frag);
     destination.append(obj.addToMe);
    }
    $( this ).appendTo(obj.addToMe);
  });
}
```

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ScwqL9F3KcOWanj692tO)